# Is there an advantage of using assets vs not using?

Tags: laravel

Is there a difference between the two codes below? The reason I'm asking is because when I use the first one the code work as expected but I get a file reference warning at the at the icon in the top-right corner of the PHPStorm in my `.blade.php` file!

The error is:

> File reference problem
>   Cannot resolve directory plugins
>   Cannot resolve directory datatables-bs4
>   Cannot resolve directory css
>   Cannot resolve directory dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css
>   "

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: `asset()` can handle some oddities if your application is on a subdomain/has an unusual URL/etc, but if that's not an issue, either of these approaches will work just fine.

Comment: There is also another difference if you use `assets()` you can implement S3 or CDNs easily

Comment: @TimLewis the code works just fine was just concerned about the error. So I shouldn't be concerned about it?

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna confirm if that was your question or not. I don't *think* it's a concern if your IDE shows that error, as long as the asset is actually loaded/functions, but I don't use PHPStorm. I'd lean towards using the `asset()` helper if you can though; if you're using Laravel, you might as well use Laravel functions :)

Comment: Im using Laravel, any reason why you would lean on asset helper function?
A kind note, I'm a beginner!

Comment: I think you need to (somehow) tell PhpStorm where your web root is. Otherwise it will look for the files starting at the project root which is one level below public which is the actual web root. It's more of a nuisance than an issue though . However I would use `asset` regardless since it ensures a valid URL is generated

Comment: @AlphyGacheru I'd echo apokryfos on this one; `asset()` is guaranteed to generate the correct URL so long as you have Laravel configured correctly (and the default configuration works for most setups without issue). Aside from that, code cleanliness and consistency; there will be other places you'll use `{{ }}`, like `href="{{ url(...) }}`, or `href="{{ route(...) }}"`, so keep it consistent and use Laravel functions.